# Transform a regular expression into another

Tags: python, regex, whitespace, transformation, tokenize

I have to write regular expressions to match some tokenizable text, and it will be cumbersome to add all the `\s*` and `\s+` where the amount of whitespace is insignificant or not required at all.

What I'd like to have is a function that accepts a regex and a list of delimiter tokens, and then add the whitespace matching for me.

For example:

```
make_whitespace(regex="foo\.(\w+)\(a\)",delimiters="()[]{},.+-")
```

should return

```
"foo\s*\.\s*(\s*\w+\s*)\(\s*a\s*\)"
```

Maybe there is already a better way to achieve this rather than hacking an existing regex; but I think using a full parser generator would be overkill. I am using Python.

Thanks.

Comment: So in addition the problem of tokenizing your text you have added the problem of tokenizing regular expressions.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski he he, true ;-)

Comment: What about something like `"\s*".join(["foo","\.","(","\w+",")\(","a","\)"])` ? On second thoughs, I guess that doesn't actually save any typing...

Comment: Though the idea sounds fine in theory, it would be really hard to do - especially for when you take capturing groups into consideration - in your example, you add whitespace both outside and inside a capturing group (where `\.(` is transformed into `\.\s*(\s*` - I believe that the regex engine will not capture any whitespace, but will allow it before the capture... which did you WANT it to do?

Comment: @CodeJockey yeah, they are greedy operators (unless appending a question mark), so the first one will get all the whitespace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added an example to the regular expression docs to show how to write a flexible tokenizer using just regular expressions:  http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/re.html#writing-a-tokenizer

It shows how to build-up the regex from pieces and how to ignore whitespace.

Alternatively, you could consider doing two passes over the inputs.  First, do an *re.sub* to replace repeated whitespace whitespace (tabs, newlines, series of spaces, etc.) with just a single space.  After that, the regexes for the actual parser will be much simpler.

Good luck.

Comment: Everybody does "flexible tokenizers" using regexes.  See any token generator used with a parser generator; the input specification for tokens is virtualy always given as a regex.

Answer (score 1):

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) could do this. It accepts language definitions as EBNF, builds ASTs, and allow you to apply [source to source](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/ProgramTransformation.html) transformations to the AST, and then regenerate text from the AST.

You'd need an EBNF for a regular expression, but that's easy.

Comment: He he, it seems that you have a really nice toolkit there, but that is even more overkill than using pyparsing or similar for this small task ^_^ anyway, +1 for the interesting reading (by the way, the second link is broken!)

Comment: @fortran: link fixed. So the bad news is regexes can't be processed with pure regexes (parentheses have to match).  So, to decide where you want do a transformation, you have have more than just the tokens.   Now its a question of what hammer do you want to use :-}